# Is there always an analytic orbit, solution to the N bodies problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q.Wang expresses analytical orbits of the N Bodies problem. What is the simpliest explanation of the uniqueness and analytical solution of the system of Newtonian differential equations ?
Ref Q.Wang The global solution of the n-body problem, Celestial Mechanics, 50,1991, p.73-88
Analytic means the Taylor's formula for an infinite radius of convergence.
Thank you

Comment: The title asks for existence.  The body asks for uniqueness.  Which one is intended?

Comment: "Analytical" is not generally the same as "analytic": it is roughly the same as "closed-form".  Of course the solutions are analytic, as long as collisions are avoided, because the differential equations are analytic.  But they are unlikely to be entire functions (i.e. have Taylor series with infinite radius of convergence).

Comment: I am french and maybe the words have not the same meaning in our langages. My question is : how can we proove the existence of a power series which domain of convergence is R, and the solution of the newtonian N Body problem ? Q.Wang gives a formal expression of this solution but is it possible to be sure it exists by general arguments ?

Comment: My question could be reformulated as follows : Do we know the existence of power series solution of the n body problem before the Q Wang's article, by general arguments concerning the non linear differential equations ? Thanks